# react-admin dataprovider specify a custom field as primary key - a field that is not named "id"

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-admin

I'm using the hasura data provider in react-admin `ra-data-hasura` (but i'm sure its more or less the same thing of `ra-data-graphql`)

My entity has their primary keys that are named differently from `id`
Is it possible to set a field as primary that is not named `id`  Eg: `MyEntityId`

Is it possible to specifiy it resource by resource (because each table could have its own name pattern) or  globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,
You have that answer in the docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiersprimary-keys-for-my-resources

you have to resolve this at the `dataProvider` level.
You have to implement your own dataProvider's methods that mapped your `MyEntityId` field to the `id` field required by react-admin.

For example (implementing getList method):

```js
const myDataProvider = {
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        return fetch(API_URL)
               .then(({ json }) => ({
                    data: json.map((record) => ({ id: record.MyEntityId, ...record })),
                    total: parseInt(json.total, 10),
                })
        );
    }
   //...
}
json.map(record => ({"id": record.userID, ...record})),
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [customize the cache IDs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-cache-ids) using the `keyFields` for each type in the `typePolicies` option of the [InMemoryCache constructor](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#configuration-options):

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  ...
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      MyEntity1: {
        keyFields: ["MyEntityId"],
      },
      MyEntity2: {
        keyFields: ["MyEntityId"],
      },
      ...
    }
  }),
  ...
})

buildHasuraProvider({ client });
```